# Connecting on-premise to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-direct-connect, aws-storage-gateway, aws-site-to-site

Can anyone tell the difference between AWS DataSync, database migration service (DMS), storage gateway, direct connect and site-to-site VPN connect? As all these are used to connect with on-premises servers.

Comment: *"As all these are used to connect with on-premises servers.*" - no, they are not. Only the last two are actually used for setting up connectivity. The others are services that transfer data, relying on existing connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/how-datasync-works.html) is responsible for **copying files** and ensuring that they were copied correctly. Think of it as a robust `robocopy` command.

> AWS DataSync is a secure, online service that automates and accelerates moving data between on premises and AWS Storage services. DataSync can copy data between Network File System (NFS) shares, Server Message Block (SMB) shares, Hadoop Distributed File Systems (HDFS), self-managed object storage, AWS Snowcone, Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) buckets, Amazon Elastic File System (Amazon EFS) file systems, Amazon FSx for Windows File Server file systems, Amazon FSx for Lustre file systems, Amazon FSz for OpenZFS file systems, and Amazon FSx for NetApp ONTAP file systems.

[AWS Data Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) **copies data between databases**, but can also send data to Amazon S3, Amazon Kinesis and Apache Kafka. It's great for data migrations between different databases and *types* of databases.

> AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) is a cloud service that makes it easy to migrate relational databases, data warehouses, NoSQL databases, and other types of data stores. You can use AWS DMS to migrate your data into the AWS Cloud or between combinations of cloud and on-premises setups.

[AWS Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/) provides a **virtual storage device** that stores data in the cloud (on S3, Glacier, FSx, etc). Think of it as a cloud-backed `H:` drive with unlimited storage.

[AWS Direct Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) links your office or data center to **AWS via fiber**. It's for high-speed, permanent connectivity to the Cloud.

> AWS Direct Connect links your internal network to an AWS Direct Connect location over a standard Ethernet fiber-optic cable. One end of the cable is connected to your router, the other to an AWS Direct Connect router. With this connection, you can create virtual interfaces directly to public AWS services (for example, to Amazon S3) or to Amazon VPC, bypassing internet service providers in your network path.

[AWS Site-to-Site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) creates a **VPN connection** between your office or data center and AWS via *existing* data connections. For example, it can create a VPN connection across your existing Internet fiber connection.

> A Site-to-Site VPN connection offers two VPN tunnels between a virtual private gateway or a transit gateway on the AWS side, and a customer gateway (which represents a VPN device) on the remote (on-premises) side.